# Why is my account denied from asking question, what I've done?

Tags: support

I don't really know what poor question I asked! And I don't see any question get downvoted, closed etc.

Anyone can check it out for me? Thx

**EDIT**

I have a lot of question that doesn't have an answer for a period, I thought it might be too specific (I couldn't find a work around answer on google) and not helping other people, neither reading or answering, so I removed them...I never know that could be a problem as well! Need to be more careful when posting questions.

Anyway, someone seems to removed the ban for me, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at your user history I see a large proportion of deleted questions (9/22 = 40%) -- These count against you in determining whether you get hit with the temporary question ban, and are almost certainly why you've been whacked with that particular stick.

[The meta question Chris S linked to in his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) goes into a lot more detail on this than you probably need, including talking about how deleted questions factor in to the ban process.

---

Most of your deleted posts look like you had a "Well ***DUH***!" moment after you posted them -- they're pretty simple questions, and I'm guessing you stumbled on the answer as you were clicking "Post Your Question".

It's perfectly acceptable to delete your Duh-Moment posts occasionally (we all have days where we catch the Dumb and can't brain), but if you find yourself doing it often (like "40% of the time") you might want to consider the possibility that you're running to Server Fault for help a little too quickly -- If you Duh almost half of your posts you're obviously capable of figuring the little things out yourself (or have someone in your organization you can turn to who answers quicker than we do).

Comment: `we all have days where we catch the Dumb and can't brain` -- I refer to them as "weekdays," and find myself having one about 71.4% of the time, in fact.

Comment: Someone fixed it for me, and I updated my question

Answer (score 6):

Your account has been blocked from asking questions temporarily. There should have been a banner with a link that explains the situation in detail.

See [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) for additional details.